# Eclipse-CDT on x86_64 system cannot link to shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I compiled a few libraries using Eclipse-CDT on windows. However, when I tried to compile them under linux gcc keeps giving me the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrequestedLib`.  I'm using the exact same build settings between the two environments (namely I made sure to add the directories that contain the libraries i need to link to).  I'm sure the system has read access rights to the files as well.  I'm not sure what to make of this.  Please help.

Edit: These are the commands that ecplise runs to build the library:

```
gcc -I/home/me/lib/ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -olibToMake.o ../libToMake.c 
gcc -L/home/me/lib/ -shared -olibToMake.so libToMake.o -lrequestedLib
```

Edit 2: The command that renders the error is the second of the two, resulting in the `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrequestedLib` being output.

Edit 3: I've confirmed that requestedLib.so is a x86_64 binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass `-L` command line options to `gcc(1)`, be sure to add the path containing the libraries to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.cond.d/<something>`.

Once you've installed your libraries you also need to run `ldconfig(8)` by hand. (Most new users forget this step because typical package managers take care of this for you when installing new libraries.)

Comment: I am passing the -L command to gcc though... "gcc -I/home/me/lib/ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -olibToMake.o ../libToMake.c"
"gcc -L/home/me/lib/ -shared -olibToMake.so libToMake.o -lrequestedLib" are the commands I run, but the output is as it said.  I'll try running the config though, jik

Comment: Nope, didn't help at all. >_>;

Comment: Hrm; can you [edit] your question and copy-paste those commands directly into it? They might be the key that helps someone solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> `gcc -I/home/me/lib/ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -olibToMake.o ../libToMake.c`
>   `gcc -L/home/me/lib/ -shared -olibToMake.so libToMake.o -lrequestedLib`

When building 64-bit shared libraries on `x86_64`, the `-fPIC` flag is usually required, or you get a `recompile with -fPIC` error at shared library link time.

Since you didn't use `-fPIC`, yet your link succeeded, you are likely using  (non-default) `gcc` that targets `i*86` (that is, produces 32-bit output). You can confirm that by running `file libToMake.so`.

You didn't show that command that *actually* fails (the one that produces `cannot find -lrequestedLib` error). I am guessing that *that* command is using a different gcc (default one?), that targets `x86_64`. If it looks something like

```
gcc main.c -L/home/me/lib -lrequestedLib
```

that command will *ignore* `/home/me/lib/librequestedLib.so` (because you can't link together 32-bit and 64-bit code), and will continue searching for `librequestedLib` elsewhere. When it can't find a 64-bit version of `librequestedLib`, it will produce the error message you are gettiing.

Comment: Tried adding *what*??? I didn't suggest that you add anything, only that you understand the problem. I am guessing you added `-fPIC`. Of *course* that wouldn't work. But *if* my guess is correct, adding `-m32` to the compile and link command for the final binary *will* work.

Comment: @CalebWaggoner Please don't cut/paste your errors into comments. Update your question instead. You *still* have not answered the most basic question: whether your `librequestedLib.so` (the one you successfully built) is a 32-bit or a 64-bit one. The fact that you keep naming it differently: `memMan.so`, `librequestedLib.so`, `libToMake.so` doesn't help either. You are just adding more confusion to the already confusing picture.

Comment: About your first assumption, the library compiles to x86_64. To your second assumption, there's only one binary gcc on my system and that obviously will not even attempt to compile something into i*86 architecture. To your third assumption, the two commands that are shown are the only that run. gcc runs ld in the background to find prereq libraries for linking.  The reason I tried what was mentioned is that it might have helped. But what I need to know, and cannot seem to divine is why gcc (or ld?) will not look in the specified directory for the library when it was told to.

Comment: @CalebWaggoner Ok, it's obvious I over-thought the problem. The problem appears trivial: there is no `librequestedLib.so` in `/home/me/lib`. What does `ls -l /home/me/lib/librequestedLib*` say?

Comment: So I added "lib" as a prefix and that seems to have fixed that linking issue. Is there a way to make it so that it will look for the lib without the prefix?  Also this lib is asking for an entry point, even though its supposed to be a shared library (it's off topic but), any thoughts?